# I've got the error message when try to call API function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have Vue.js app and call API function from Vue component. The code looks as following:

1. component.vue:

```
<script>
import gpbApi from '@/utils/api/gpbApi';

methods: {
    async load() {
        const result = await gpbApi.catalogProducts.getList(this.entityId);
        this.typesOfApplication = result;
    },
```

2. gpbApi.js:

```
import catalogProducts from './catalogProducts';

export default {
    catalogProducts,
};
```

3. catalogProducts.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost/client/';

export async function getList(entityId) {
    if (entityId == null) return;
    const { data } = await axios.get(`api/getList?id=${entityId}`);
    return data;
}
```

gpbApi.js and catalogProducts.js files are placed in `/utils/api/` folder.

I've got the following error:

```
mounted hook (Promise/async) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getList')
    at VueComponent.load (component.vue:103:1)
```

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a default import although you didn't declare the default export.

Either use:

```
import * as gpbApi from '@/utils/api/gpbApi';
```

or

```
import { getList } from '@/utils/api/gpbApi';
```

Comment: I've got another error now: "mounted hook (Promise/async) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'catalogProducts')". I've tried what you suggested with importing catalogProducts.js, but it doesn't work.

Comment: When you use the second version, you have to use the variable you imported directly, no through `gpbApi.name`

Comment: Ok. I've used first version and got the error again: "mounted hook (Promise/async) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProductReqtypeList')".

Comment: I don't see you using `getProductReqtypeList` anywhere in your code

Comment: Excuse me. It's getList(). I've changed function name.

Comment: `import catalogProducts from './catalogProducts';` this is `undefined` please read how to import stuff

Comment: I would like to have the possibility to write as following: gpbApi.catalogProducts.getList(), gpbApi.users.getUser(), gpbApi.accounts.getAccount() etc., where catalogProducts, users, accounts etc., are particular API files.

Comment: Then stop exporting `default` and importing `default`